# I want to know why it takes time between discoverServices() and onGetService().

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I developed an app that uses ble. I was using Eclipse as a development tool.

My "app that uses ble" is installed on my smartphone. And I connected my smartphone and pc to usb. Then on my smartphone, I launched the "app that uses ble" that I developed.

And I found the following logs at Logcat of Eclipse.

```
08-22 20:59:11.278: V/BluetoothLeService(23378): report STATE_CONNECTED
08-22 20:59:11.283: E/BluetoothLeService(23378): ccccc BluetoothGattCallback public void onConnectionStateChange end
08-22 20:59:11.283: I/MainActivity2(23378): BroadcastReceiver CONNECTED
08-22 20:59:11.288: I/MainActivity2(23378): BroadcastReceiver GATT_SUCCESS
08-22 20:59:11.288: I/BluetoothLeService(23378): getBtGatt()
08-22 20:59:11.288: V/MainActivity2(23378): onView mServicesRdy = false
08-22 20:59:11.288: V/MainActivity2(23378): onView mBtGatt = android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@4335ebb8
08-22 20:59:11.288: I/BluetoothLeService(23378): getNumServices()
08-22 20:59:11.288: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): discoverServices() - device: 98:7B:F3:52:48:11
08-22 20:59:11.288: E/MainActivity2(23378): mBtGatt.discoverServices() = true
08-22 20:59:11.288: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): discoverServices() - device: 98:7B:F3:52:48:11
08-22 20:59:15.188: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): onGetService() - Device=98:7B:F3:52:48:11 UUID=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-22 20:59:15.188: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): onGetService() - Device=98:7B:F3:52:48:11 UUID=00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-22 20:59:15.188: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): onGetService() - Device=98:7B:F3:52:48:11 UUID=0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-22 20:59:15.188: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): onGetService() - Device=98:7B:F3:52:48:11 UUID=f000aa00-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
08-22 20:59:15.188: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): onGetService() - Device=98:7B:F3:52:48:11 UUID=f000aa60-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
08-22 20:59:15.193: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): onGetService() - Device=98:7B:F3:52:48:11 UUID=f000ccc0-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
```

In the above log,

```
08-22 20:59:11.288: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): discoverServices() - device: 98:7B:F3:52:48:11
08-22 20:59:15.188: D/BluetoothGatt(23378): onGetService() - Device=98:7B:F3:52:48:11 UUID=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

This takes about 3~4 seconds.

I want to know why it takes about 3~4 seconds in this part.

Comment: it totally depends on the Android device you are using, bluetooth device you are connecting to, connection conditions, etc. In other words the answer is *just because it is this way*

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Discovering services takes time because the Bluetooth GATT protocol kind of sucks and is very badly optimized. It's a chatty protocol requiring many requests and responses. A much better idea would be to just request "give me the GATT structure" and then the GATT server responds with a burst with all info.

The time it takes depends on how many services, characteristics and descriptors the peripheral's GATT server has. It also depends on if the UUIDs are 16-bit UUIDs or 128-bit UUIDs. It has nothing to do with that the Android OS is slow or similar.

Newer Android versions (6 and up if I remember correctly) temporarily change connection interval to 7.5 ms during the GATT discover just to make it faster.

You can either check the HCI log on your Android device or use an air sniffer to look at this discovering process.

One easy fix to sometimes make it faster is that the peripheral, after connection setup requests a larger MTU.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is Bluetooth framework dependent. All Bluetooth LE actions are asynchronous and return immediately but their function is carried out based on the OS's own internal scheduling. Normally starting a scan may start very fast, but certain times it can be delayed before your device scanned callback will be fired. I've usually noticed the delay when using Bluetooth functionality on a device that has been recently powered off or set idle for a substantial amount of time. Normally after the first scan all subsequent scans were speedy and responsive.

I think the OS performs some battery saving operation and internally shuts down the Bluetooth radios (this is only speculative and I haven't performed any testing to prove this).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. if so, can the firmware have a greater impact than the app program?

Comment: @전철우 I mean the app cannot do more than what the API's provide. A lot of the Bluetooth internals are abstracted away so apps cannot do anything dangerous. The Bluetooth API essentially only offers a subset of the full capabilities of the hardware. There is no way, at least to my knowledge for an app to circumvent the Bluetooth APIs and gain direct control of the hardware.